# An R function to perform t-test to compare means and output result in a tidy way

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy, broom

I have dataframes with the following structure (one character and 3 numeric), but the names of numeric columns varies:

```
structure(list(treatment = c("product", "product", "product", "product", "product", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control"), t0 = 1:10, t1 = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19), t2 = c(1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28)), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

 treatment    t0    t1    t2
   <chr>     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 product       1     1     1
 2 product       2     3     4
 3 product       3     5     7
 4 product       4     7    10
 5 product       5     9    13
 6 control       6    11    16
 7 control       7    13    19
 8 control       8    15    22
 9 control       9    17    25
10 control      10    19    28
```

I would like to set a function to be able to perform t-test and compare means (t1 vs t0 and t2 vs t0). However this function needs to be able to work in all dataframes I have, that is, including those where numeric columns are not called t0, t1, t2. So I thought it might work by calling the column numbers inside the function, but t.test function seems to not accept that. In addition, it would be nice to have the results of the function in a tidy way. In the end, it would work like:

```
my_ttest_func(df)

 t1_t0        t     estimate   p_value
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 product   5.94     7.19    0.0000104
2 control   1.98     2.32    0.0327  

 t2_t0        t     estimate  p_value
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 product   4.20     5.86   0.000339
2 control   1.95     2.55   0.0343
```

I got results close to the way I expect by pivoting the df to a long format but only works by calling the levels I want to compare. Also gives only one comparison, so I should call the function two times. As the structure of my dataframes are always the same I could put the following code inside `my_ttest_func()` but need to refer to time levels in a universal way.

```
df %>% pivot_longer(!treatment, names_to = "time", values_to = "values") %>%
  group_by(treatment) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = values, ~ list(broom::tidy(t.test(.[time == "t2"], 
                                                             .[time == "t0"], 
                                                             alternative = "greater", 
                                                             paired=TRUE)) %>%
             select(statistic, estimate, p.value)))) %>% 
  unnest(values)


  treatment statistic estimate  p.value
  <chr>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 control        9.90       14 0.000292
2 product        2.83        4 0.0237
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? How does your function look like and what errors did you get?

Comment: just made some edits to make it more clear

Comment: If there are three numeric columns and they aren't named `t0`, `t1` and `t2`, how does your function "know" which ones to use for the t_test? Should it always be the second column vs. the third and second vs fourth?

Comment: exactly, t0 is always in the same position

Comment: maybe it would not be easy to have the results for the two comparisons (t0 vs ? and t0 vs ?), but would be great if it work for at least one comparison. The challenge is make the t-test understand column positions, because, as I said, they are not always called t1 and t2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested `map`-function:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  split(~treatment) %>% 
  map_dfr(
    ~.x %>% 
      summarise(
        across(
          3:4, 
          ~t.test(.x, 
                  !!sym(colnames(df)[2]), 
                  alternative = "greater", 
                  paired=TRUE) %>% 
            broom::tidy() %>% 
            select(statistic, estimate, p.value) 
          )
        ) %>% 
        map_dfr(bind_rows, .id = "name"),
    .id = "treatment") %>% 
  arrange(name, treatment)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  treatment name  statistic estimate  p.value
  <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 control   t1         9.90        7 0.000292
2 product   t1         2.83        2 0.0237  
3 control   t2         9.90       14 0.000292
4 product   t2         2.83        4 0.0237
```

which is not exactly your desired output but something you could work on.

Since your `t0` column is always in second place, we could use the column name as an input for `t.test` inside the `summarise(across(...))` construct.

The new column `name` contains the variable `t0` is tested with.

Comment: Great!! The way you called the column inside the `t.test()` is interesting. Thank you very much for your help. Hope this question and solution may help others.